# "Invalid Binary" in iTunes Connect(for OSX)

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store, submit

I have developed an application on OSX.

I tried to upload it on MAC App Store, however it said "**Invalid Binary**".

My **XCode version** is **4.5** and **OS version** is **10.7.5**.

And in the plist file,

- "**Architecture**" = "**Standard (32/64-bit Intel)**"
- "**Base SDK**" = "**OS X 10.8**"
- "**Supported Platforms**" = "**OS X**"
- "**Valid Architectures**" = "**i386 x86_64**"
- "**Code Signing Entitlements**" is empty
- "**Code Signing Identify**" = "**3rd Party MAC Developer Application**"

What did I wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you please explain more about the sandbox?

Comment: Oh,  thank you! It should be sandboxed!

Comment: @JinX Did you ever find the solution? I got the same problem...